# Import class from another file in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

My problem is that I want to use my Appointment class in my app.ts file.

I reference it in my app.ts on the top:

```
/// <reference path="Appointment.ts"/>
```

Then I instantiate it and print the clientID:

```
var app : Appointment = new Appointment(1, 2, "User", 3);;

console.log(app.ClientID);
```

But then I get `ReferenceError: Appointment is not defined`

I also added the .js script of Appointment to my html file.

My Appointment looks like this:

```
class Appointment {
    // some properties

    constructor(clientID: number, state: number, userCreated: string, activityID: number) {
        // constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the generated js file to see if the Appointment class was compiled into javascript. If it wasn't check for compilation errors in your class.

Comment: Yes it compiles to a Appointment.js file.

Comment: Try to write this code in the Appointment.ts file. If it works, then as you said this should be a reference path problem(check the path). If not, then it's weird and I need some more info in order to help you..

Comment: Is appointment.js loaded before App.js?

Comment: If I copy the Appointment in my app.ts file it works! So it's a reference error. How do I reference it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script references should look like this (order is important... and `.js` file extension is important too!)

```
<script src="Appointment.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh god. Can't believe I did it the wrong way! :D  Thank you!!